# Override style of element when tbody is hovered

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem in `:hover`.

I want to make the last `tr` of that `tbody` also change color when its `tbody` is hovered. The problem is the last `tr` has its own class.

Here is the structure of my code:

```css
.cust-table {
  border: 1px solid black;  
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.cust-table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cust-table tbody:nth-child(even){
  background-color: white;
}

.cust-table tbody:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: green;
}

.cust-color {
  background-color: blue; 
}

.cust-table tbody:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="cust-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">A</td>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cust-color">
      <td  colspan="3">Cust color</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">B</td>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cust-color">
      <td  colspan="3">Cust color</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">C</td>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cust-color">
      <td  colspan="3">Cust color</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried adding `cust-color:hover` but as expected, it only works when the `<tr>` with `cust-color` is hovered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this rule to set the custom color only if the `tbody` is not hovered:

```
tbody:not(:hover) .cust-color {
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

```css
.cust-table {
  border: 1px solid black;  
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.cust-table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cust-table tbody:nth-child(even){
  background-color: white;
}

.cust-table tbody:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: green;
}

tbody:not(:hover) .cust-color {
  background-color: blue; 
}

.cust-table tbody:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="cust-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">A</td>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cust-color">
      <td  colspan="3">Cust color</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">B</td>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cust-color">
      <td  colspan="3">Cust color</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">C</td>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cust-color">
      <td  colspan="3">Cust color</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ori Drori's answer is probably the best, but here is an alternative solution:

```
.cust-table tbody:hover, .cust-table tbody:hover tr.cust-color {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Overrides the tr color when its parent tbody is hovered.

Comment: Thank you!
I agree with you, Ori Drori's answer is the simplest and best solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule for that specific `tr`:

```
.cust-table tbody:hover,
.cust-table tbody:hover .cust-color{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```